# Nginx is not able to redirect from login to homepage with Flask app running on AWS EC2 instances

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an Internet facing ELB which forwards all my request to Nginx server at port 8080
(Nginx web server).This Nginx server is suppose to forward all the request to my Flask app which listens at port 8080 from application Load balancer.
So here is the flow :
Internet Facing ALB (80) --> NGINX (reverse proxy)8080 --> Internal ALB (8080)--> Flask App (8080). Now the problem is my redirects do not work

I tried to use proxy_pass in nginx.conf (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf) as below

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    listen       [::]:8080;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

     location = / {
                proxy_pass http://my-internal-alb.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/login;
                proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         }

    location = /login {
                 proxy_pass http://my-internal-alb.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/login;
                 proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                 proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         }
     location = /signup {
                         proxy_pass http://my-internal-alb.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/signup;
                         proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                         proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
                         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                 }
```

Also my Flask App Code

```
    @studio_api_blueprint.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            db_object = users.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
            if db_object is None or db_object.username != form.username.data or db_object.password != form.password.data:
                flash('Invalid username or password')
                return redirect(url_for('studioAPI.login'))
            login_user(db_object, form.remember_me.data)
            print(current_user.username)
            return redirect(url_for('studioAPI.first'))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)


@studio_api_blueprint.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        db_object = users(username=form.username.data, password=form.password.data, fname=form.firstname.data,
                          lname=form.lastname.data)
        db.session.add(db_object)
        db.session.commit()
        db.session.flush()
        flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user with username {}! Please login below.'.format(
            form.username.data))
        return redirect(url_for('studioAPI.login'))
    return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
```

Now issue is when I am at signup page and user fills in signup data and I submit - nginx seems like not redirecting me to login page, please note, locally when I tested this (all redirections works ok), so issue is after successful signup the '/signup' does not redirects to /login page  .I am not sure if I am doing this the right way . Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Sure I just edited and added formatted code . Thanks

Comment: Does the URL change in the browser?

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't have to describe every location in nginx like that just the `/` one should suffice.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary yes the url changes in browser but it is not redirecting. For example it is supposed to go to <url of internet alb>/login it is going to <url of internet alb>:8080/login . I am not sure why it is adding :8080

Comment: @MG did you find a solution because I think I have the same issue?